# Campaign Influence for Visualforce Page relatedlist is not working

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I tried to use the code below but it doesn't work. Please help because I'm trying everything and I can't find the api childname for it.

```
  <apex:relatedList list="CampaignInfluence" title="Campaign Influence"/> and

  <apex:relatedList list="CampaignInfluences" title="Campaign Influence"/>
```

Error message:

- 'CampaignInfluence' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Opportunity 
  or
- 'CampaignInfluences' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Opportunity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `CampaignInfluences`:

[image]

but you won't be able to see that the object or the relationship exists unless you have the App Permission `Campaign Influence` turned on. It is not on by default, even for System Administrators.

[image]

Of course, the feature itself must also be turned on at the org level in Setup.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. I just use this document. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317075&type=1

Comment: It works David but why it doesn't show the 'Add to Campaign' button? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, @khmerforce - you might need to add it to the layout as well, or you might need some additional permissioning. I have fairly limited experience with this feature.

Comment: So it is showing the same thing for you or you have the 'Add to Campaign' Button?